# Deploy/Reload code from python pyramid project in production

Tags: python, pyramid

I use `...\pserve development.ini --reload` in my dev environment to restart my API when code change.

The doc says:

> Auto-template-reload behavior is not recommended for production sites
>   as it slows rendering slightly; it’s usually only desirable during
>   development.

But the doc has no proposition for a production environment. What's the recommendation to reload, do I have to make it manually every time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to restart the service if you change anything in your config file.

If you know that you'll be changing things and don't want to restart it every time that happens, move some of your configs to a database and refactor your app to read from that. This won't be possible for everything, and you'll need to be careful that when an update happens it is applied correctly, but it can be done for some things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was asking for the code change, not for config change. I think that your answer is not related to my question.

Comment: @Michael Yes, you will need to restart the app manually when you make a code change.

Comment: For both code and config changes you should restart your app manually in production to ensure everything is properly reloaded. The automatic reloading features that are built into the code are for an improved development experience but they are not perfect and are not intended to be robust to any type of code/config changes you would make - thus leaving your production code running in inconsistent states.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are talking about the section of the documentation, [Automatically Reloading Templates](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/templates.html#automatically-reloading-templates). That only discusses how to reload templates automatically, not your entire application.

The documentation explicitly states not to use `--reload` in production. That is an *automatic* function, not a *manual* one.

If you change your code and deploy it to a production environment, it is assumed that you would restart your application *manually*, thereby removing the need to use `--reload` when invoking `pserve production.ini`.